# PCV valve location

Tags: peugeot, pcv-valve, vacuum-hoses

I'm looking for the PCV valve in my Peugeot 106 1.1 TU1JP (HFX) year 2000.

I can't find it, the closest thing I found is a hose going from the cam cover to the air filter, the connector on the air filter goes to a simple thin rubber diaphragm facing inside the air filter case. Is this some kind of PCV?

thanks

Comment: That is the other half of the PCV system, fresh air intake.

Comment: where should i look? Been looking like a week already :)

Comment: Probably in the valve cover or close to it.